# How to dynamically change HTML content of a page with information from a PHP file?

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array, associative-array

So, I have a php file called db.php to replicate some sort of database. This is basically a file with some multidimensional associative arrays:

```
<?php
$arrShowcases = array(
    "1"=>array("title"=>"Landing Page", "descr"=>"Welcome!", "img"=>"actions-landing.jpg", "polygon"=>array(
        0=> array(
                "points"=>"1338,4,1338,50,1272,50,1272,4",
                "link"=>"69", 
                "modalbody"=>"This button lets you Signup on the webapp",
                "modaltitle"=>"Signup Button"
            ),
        1=> array(
                "points"=>"1246,12,1249,44,1206,44,1204,14",
                "link"=>"2", 
                "modalbody"=>"This button redirects you for the login form",
                "modaltitle"=>"Login Button"
            )
    )),
    "2"=>array("title"=>"Login page", "descr"=>"Make your login", "img"=>"actions-login.jpg", "polygon"=>array(
        0=> array(
            "points"=>"1338,4,1338,50,1272,50,1272,4",
            "link"=>"69", 
            "modalbody"=>"This button lets you Signup on the webapp",
            "modaltitle"=>"Signup Button"
            ),
        1=> array(
            "points"=>"1246,12,1249,44,1206,44,1204,14",
            "link"=>"69", 
            "modalbody"=>"This button redirects you for your dashboard",
            "modaltitle"=>"Login Button"
            )
    ))
);
?>
```

Then, I have a html page with a section element where I need to change page header title, subtitle, image and some polygon points:

```
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <?php include cfgPath."/includes/menu.html"; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <h1 class="page-header"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i> Landing page</h1>
          <h3>// Lorem ipsum...</h3>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="position:relative;">
              <img id="pageScreenshot" src="<?php echo cfgRoot; ?>/assets/images/actions-landing.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Landing Page"/>
              <svg id="svgImageMap" width="1366" height="768">
                <polygon points="1338,4,1338,50,1272,50,1272,4" data-originalpoints="1338,4 1338,50 1272,50 1272,4" data-id="0"/>
                <polygon points="1246,12,1249,44,1206,44,1204,14" data-originalpoints="1246,12 1249,44 1206,44 1204,14" data-id="1"/>
                <polygon points="378,43,446,42,445,11,377,9" data-originalpoints="378,43 446,42 445,11 377,9" data-id="2"/>
                <polygon points="196,10,367,10,366,42,195,43" data-originalpoints="196,10 367,10 366,42 195,43" data-id="3"/>
                <polygon points="121,16,120,35,164,39,164,17" data-originalpoints="121,16 120,35 164,39 164,17" data-id="4"/>
                <polygon points="14,15,13,40,95,43,95,12" data-originalpoints="14,15 13,40 95,43 95,12" data-id="5">
              </svg>
            </div>
            <!-- data original points: X1,Y1 X2,Y2 X3,Y3 X4,Y4 -->
            </br>
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block" href="<?php echo cfgRoot; ?>/app/showcase/showcaseView.php">Go Back</a>
          </div> <!-- colmd12 -->
        </div> <!-- colmd9 -->
      </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- container -->
  </section> <!-- section -->
```

As you can see on the above html for the section element, I wrote by hand all the information. However, my goal is to change that info with stuff provided from the db.php file.

I want something like this nameofthepage.php?id=1 (and all the info provided in the position 1 of the array goes to the html) or this: nameofthepage.php?id=2 (and all the info provided in the position 2 of the array goes to the html). Any advice or tip to get this behavior?

So far, I tried to do echos like this:

```
<?php echo $arrShowcases[positions-that-i-want]["information-that-i-want"]; ?>
```

to change the hardcoded html but that doesn't get me the dynamic behavior I need.

Comment: What have you tried? It reads like you're asking for someone to just do it for you. All you need to do is get the `?id` parameter with `$_GET['id']` and then reference the appropriate part of the array, e.g. `$arrShowcases[1]['title']` is the title for page 1, etc...

Comment: Typical case for AJAX.

Comment: @iquellis Not really because it can be generated on a server. No need for asynchronous calling.

Comment: @Andy I didn't asked for someone to do it for me, I asked for an advice or tip and thanks for that. I updated the question with what I tried and I don't know more because I never worked with PHP, neither AJAX or whatsoever before.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you'll get the point.

```
<?php
    //-----------------------------
    // If id is not sent then stop with page execution. You can redirect or something else.
    if(!isset($_GET["id"])) {
        die("ID not received.");
    }
    // Get that received id because at this point we are sure that id is received because page execution did not stopped before.
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    //-----------------------------
    // Import your "database".
    require_once "db.php";
    //-----------------------------
    // If there is no page with that id, stop page execution.
    if(!isset($arrShowcases[$id])) {
        die("page does not exists.");
    }
    // If there is a page then store it in a variable.
    $page = $arrShowcases[$id];
    //-----------------------------
?>
<section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <?php include cfgPath."/includes/menu.html"; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <h1 class="page-header">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
              <?= $page['title']; ?> // Echo page title.
          </h1>
          <h3><?= $page['descr']; ?></h3> // Echo page description.
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="position:relative;">
              <img id="pageScreenshot" src="<?php echo cfgRoot; ?>/assets/images/<?= $page['img']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?= $page['title']; ?>"/> // Echo image filename and page title.
              <svg id="svgImageMap" width="1366" height="768">
                // For each polygon, echo it's points and key as an index (0, 1, 2, 3...)
                <?php foreach ($page["polygon"] as $key => $value) { ?>
                    <polygon points="<?= $value['points']; ?>" data-originalpoints="<?= $value['points']; ?>" data-id="<?= $key; ?>"/>
                <?php } ?>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <!-- data original points: X1,Y1 X2,Y2 X3,Y3 X4,Y4 -->
            </br>
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block" href="<?php echo cfgRoot; ?>/app/showcase/showcaseView.php">Go Back</a>
          </div> <!-- colmd12 -->
        </div> <!-- colmd9 -->
      </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- container -->
  </section> <!-- section -->
```

Comment: Are you kidding me? It's well documented for anybody with common sense.

Comment: I think there is nothing to clarify here. It's self explanatory. If he's able to create that multi-dimensional array all by himself, I'm sure he will figure it out. Please, stop commenting if you are not offering a better answer.

Comment: My comment already improved your answer, but @Andy gave a better one as a comment, no need to fish for points. SO is a community to exchange opinions, learn to deal with that in a positive way.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter an URL in the browser, you are making a GET HTTP request.
That request can take variables in the form of parameters, by adding `?` to the end of your URL and then all the parameters you need, separated by `&`, like this(based on your example):

`nameofthepage.php?id=1&another=2`

In PHP, you can catch those parameters using the superglobal [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), like this:

`$id = $_GET['id'];`

By now you should understand [@Spectarion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45618709/870949) answer, that solves your problem.
I don't think any answer should be marked as correct, because these are the basics of working with HTTP with PHP, but that is up to you.